# How to draw multiple objects using a VBO and a single OpenGL drawelements call?

Tags: opengl, graphics, rendering, real-time, vbo

I've read that it is possible to draw multiple objects using a vbo and using single drawelements call.  I haven't found any examples of this.  Right now I'm making a drawelements call per cube drawn which is killing my frame rate since I'm making the entire game out of them.  Any help is appreciated, especially example code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, just put all your data into one long VBO and then make the `glDrawElements()` call on all of it. Though you probably won't be able to use any of the `GL_*_STRIP` types for drawing separate objects.

Comment: glPrimitiveRestartIndex() can help if you want to render multiple strips in a single draw call